# How do I recompile C# programs to run on ARM CPUs?

Tags: c#, x86, windows-8, arm, windows-rt

I've made a couple desktop applications with C#, using Windows Forms Application.

As you know, on most Windows 8 tablets, the CPU is ARM, and cannot run programs that are written for Intel 8086 processors.

Can I somehow recompile my Windows Forms Application programs to work on ARM processors, so tablet users can run them? I'm using Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows RT only allowed signed applications to run, and of course Microsoft won't allow signing desktop apps except for their own applications. So the only way you can do (legally) is buying a MS dev account and develop Metro (Modern) UI apps. Or if you dare, [jailbreak](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-unlock-your-windows-rt-device/) it and install ported desktop applications. There is a list of ported apps for windows RT on [xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2092348).

But there are lots of x86 Windows 8 tablet nowadays, and it's not easy to find a windows RT one. Jailbreak and write desktop apps for windows RT may not worth the effort.